# Given its pseudo-inverse, is there a fast way to measure the degree of full-rankness of a nonsquare matrix?

Tags: matrices, inverse

update: I realized the core of question is about ill-conditioning of the matrix (aka Multicollinearity).
In a computer, with floating point arithmetic, it is impossible to talk about full-rankness. We can only measure the degree in which it occurs.
Thus, I still have a question. Better rewritten.

I have seen in StackOverflow suggestions of dividing the biggest singular value by the smallest. Is performing an entire SVD really the fastest solution?

---

I am writing a software that needs to check the full-rankness of a matrix M.
It makes use of a fast linear algebra library (LAPACK).
Since it also needs the pseudo-inverse of the matrix,
it performs Singular Value Decomposition first, to be able to calculate the rank.
After that it calculates the pseudo-inverse.

However, if we measure only the SVD part of the calculation,
it is already twice slower than my entire previous pseudo-inverse calculation "pinvRR" (which was based on ridge regression theory).

Can I take advantage of the pinvRR result to check if the matrix is full-rank?

Comment: pseudo-inverse.

Comment: SVD turned out to be much more stable numerically than ridge regression.

Comment: You can estimate the conditional number without running SVD...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are using LAPACK, it has [DGECON](http://www.netlib.org/lapack/double/dgecon.f) function which estimates the reciprocal of the condition number of a real matrix in $\| .\|_1$ or $\|.\|_{\infty}$. It's a way faster than SVD and gives pretty good estimate (internally it performs  LU decomposition).

Comment: Yes I am using LAPACK via MTJ (netlib). Sounds good, I need some time to test it. Any practical considerations on how to assess the returned value are welcome.

Comment: Actually, Matlab uses the same implementation. So, if you just want to check, run $rcond(A)$ (if $A$ is ill-conditioned the result will be close to 0)